# Entry(self, textvar=firstName) gives NameError: name 'firstName' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically I am working on creating a program with different windows/frames. On each of these frames I am looking to have a different mini program for example one window allowing for a login page and then another allowing for registering. Currently I am able to switch between each frame with buttons and have labels on each frame. I have a separate program which allows for the registration of an account and information about them and then another separate program which allows for the logging in of an account which checks if that information is correct within the database which is created.

My main problem now is basically merging this altogether with different frames allowing for different functions on my overall program. My main problem currently is whenever I add in an entry box the program proceeds to give errors for my *init* which I don't understand.(Sorry I am not very advanced in my programming knowledge to be able to do this so that's why I am asking for help)

[[image: This is the error I get from when I add in an entrybox and even when I fix the variable by doing firstName = StringVar() it still isnt fixed]

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import sqlite3



    class App(Tk):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
                    Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="fishicon3.ico")
                    Tk.wm_title(self, "Crumlin Fishing Club")


                    #Setup Menu
                    MainMenu(self)
                    #Setup Frame
                    container = Frame(self)
                    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
                    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
                    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

                    self.frames = {}

                    for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
                            frame = F(container, self)
                            self.frames[F] = frame
                            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

                    self.show_frame(StartPage)  
            def show_frame(self, context):
                    frame = self.frames[context]
                    frame.tkraise()

    class StartPage(Frame):
            def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                    Frame.__init__(self, parent)

                    label = Label(self, text="Start Page")
                    label.place(x=30,y=5)
                    start_page = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Page", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
                    start_page.place(x=25,y=25)
                    page_one = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne))
                    page_one.place(x=25,y=50)
                    page_two = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
                    page_two.place(x=25,y=75)
                    lblWelcome = Label(self, text="WELCOME! Welcome to the website of the Crumlin and District Angling Association owners of the fishing rights to the Crumlin River, Co. Antrim.",width=115,font=("bold", 10))
                    lblWelcome.place(x=500,y=50)





    class PageOne(Frame):
            def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                    Frame.__init__(self, parent)

                    label = Label(self, text="Page One")
                    label.place(x=30,y=5)
                    firstNameLabel = Label(self, text="First Name",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
                    firstNameLabel.place(x=350,y=100)
                    secondNameLabel = Label(self, text="Second Name",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
                    secondNameLabel.place(x=350,y=125)
                    usernameLabel = Label(self, text="Username",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
                    usernameLabel.place(x=350,y=150)
                    passwordLabel = Label(self, text="Password",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
                    passwordLabel.place(x=350,y=175)
                    genderLabel = Label(self, text="Gender",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
                    genderLabel.place(x=350,y=200)
                    countryLabel = Label(self, text="Country",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
                    countryLabel.place(x=350,y=225)
                    start_page = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Page", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
                    start_page.place(x=25,y=25)
                    page_one = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne))
                    page_one.place(x=25,y=50)
                    page_two = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
                    page_two.place(x=25,y=75)


    def database():
                    Username = username.get()
                    Password = password.get()
                    Gender = gender.get()
                    Country = country.get()
                    Animal = animal.get()
                    FirstName = firstName.get()
                    SecondName = secondName.get()
                    conn = sqlite3.connect('Database1.db')
                    with conn:
                            cursor=conn.cursor()
                    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student (FirstName TEXT,SecondName TEXT,Gender TEXT,Country TEXT,Animal TEXT,username TEXT,password TEXT)')
                    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Student (FirstName,SecondName,Gender,Country,Animal,Username,Password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(FirstName,SecondName,Gender,Country,Animal,Username,Password))
                    conn.commit()

    class PageTwo(Frame):
            def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                    Frame.__init__(self, parent)

                    label = Label(self, text="Page Two")
                    label.place(x=30,y=5)
                    start_page = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Page", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(StartPage))
                    start_page.place(x=25,y=25)
                    page_one = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageOne))
                    page_one.place(x=25,y=50)
                    page_two = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
                    page_two.place(x=25,y=75)

    class MainMenu:
            def __init__(self, master):
                    menubar = Menu(master)
                    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
                    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=master.quit)
                    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
                    master.config(menu=menubar)


    app=App()
    app.geometry("1900x1000+0+0")
    app.mainloop()
```

So thats basically the windows of my main program and I am trying to implement then on "page one" registration for an account and then on another page a login function but for now I will show my registration program only as I do not know how to implement this on page one.

```
  from tkinter import *
  import sqlite3

  root = Tk()
  root.geometry('800x400')
  root.title("Membership Application")


  username=StringVar()
  password=StringVar()
  gender=StringVar()
  country=StringVar()
  animal=StringVar()
  firstName=StringVar()
  secondName=StringVar()

  def database():
     Username=username.get()
     Password=password.get()
     Gender=gender.get()
     Country=country.get()
     Animal=animal.get()
     FirstName=firstName.get()
     SecondName=secondName.get()
     conn = sqlite3.connect('Database1.db')
     with conn:
        cursor=conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student (FirstName TEXT,SecondName TEXT,Gender TEXT,Country TEXT,Animal TEXT,username TEXT,password TEXT)')
     cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Student (FirstName,SecondName,Gender,Country,Animal,Username,Password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(FirstName,SecondName,Gender,Country,Animal,Username,Password))
     conn.commit()

  title = Label(root, text="Registration form",width=20,font=("bold", 20))
  title.place(x=90,y=53)

  firstNameLabel = Label(root, text="First Name",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
  firstNameLabel.place(x=50,y=100)

  firstNameEntry = Entry(root,textvar=firstName)
  firstNameEntry.place(x=200,y=100)

  secondNameLabel = Label(root, text="Second Name",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
  secondNameLabel.place(x=50,y=125)

  secondNameEntry = Entry(root,textvar=secondName)
  secondNameEntry.place(x=200,y=125)

  usernameLabel = Label(root, text="Username",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
  usernameLabel.place(x=350,y=100)

  usernameEntry = Entry(root,textvar=username)
  usernameEntry.place(x=500,y=100)

  passwordLabel = Label(root, text="Password",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
  passwordLabel.place(x=350,y=125)

  passwordEntry = Entry(root,textvar=password, show ="*")
  passwordEntry.place(x=500,y=125)

  genderLabel = Label(root, text="Gender",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
  genderLabel.place(x=70,y=230)

  Radiobutton(root, text="Male",padx = 5, variable=gender, value="Male").place(x=235,y=230)
  Radiobutton(root, text="Female",padx = 20, variable=gender, value="Female").place(x=290,y=230)

  countryLabel = Label(root, text="Country",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
  countryLabel.place(x=70,y=280)

  countryList = ['Canada','India','UK','Nepal','Iceland','South Africa'];

  droplist=OptionMenu(root,country, *countryList)
  droplist.config(width=15)
  country.set('Select your country') 
  droplist.place(x=240,y=280)

  label_4 = Label(root, text="Animals",width=20,font=("bold", 10))
  label_4.place(x=85,y=330)
  animal2= IntVar()
  Checkbutton(root, text="Dog", variable=animal).place(x=235,y=330)
  Checkbutton(root, text="Cat", variable=animal2).place(x=290,y=330)

  Button(root, text='Submit',width=20,bg='brown',fg='white',command=database).place(x=500,y=280)

  root.mainloop()
```

This last bit wouldnt turn into code but this is still part of the registration program.
So basically how do I implement this I have tried multiple ways of trying to bring over the entry boxes and have the database work as well but this just isn't merging together and there is nowhere I have looked explaining how to do this specific task of having different features on each frame.

Comment: Please don't link to a picture of the error. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format the error.

Comment: Is the indentation we see in the question the actual indentation?

Comment: OK sorry @BryanOakley Oakley and I believe it is the actual indentation. If it does not run then there must be a mistake... :(

Comment: @StackOverflowUser please improve the indentation.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have improved indentation

Comment: @BryanOakley I have improved indentation